# ' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs

I've tried to solve this problem for more than a week. I'm new to this meteor. I'm trying to learn by myself even because I do not know English very well.
but I'm trying to access an api that I get this eh encotrado that you should put a message like

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

but I do not know how and where

also try to put `{mode: 'no-cors'}`

`fetch('http://sipla.cuci.udg.mx/sc/horariop.php?c=219359735&k=0d8ce4fab5f4df9ce711cae81e044e1a',{mode: 'no-cors'})` no work for me

```
componentDidMount() {

              fetch('http://sipla.cuci.udg.mx/sc/horariop.php?c=219359735&k=0d8ce4fab5f4df9ce711cae81e044e1a')

        .then((response) => {
          return response.json()
        })
        .then((dat) => { 
            this.setState( {datos1: dat })
        })    
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're getting a CORS error when trying to hit that URL; you can add reverse-proxy CORS prefix to the URL to make your call to bypass it;

Just prepend 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' to the URL and you shouldn't get that cross origin error;

```
var url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://sipla.cuci.udg.mx/sc/horariop.php?c=219359735&k=0d8ce4fab5f4df9ce711cae81e044e1a';
fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers:{
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log('Success:', response))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

Comment: thank you, but I show up in console,
but what I wanted was to save it in variables and put it in web no console 
{this.state.res.map (dat  =>  {
              return  (
                <tr key={dat.c}>
                  <td>{dat.codigo}</td>
                  <td>{dat.nombre}</td>
                  <td>{dat.carrera}</td>

Comment: Not that using a middle-man was ever a great idea, that open proxy has been largely constrained now. It encourages you to self-host if you want to do this as a "real" fix. [More info here](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301).